# Image won't stretch vertically to browser size

Tags: html, css, stretch

I'm trying to have a large background image stretch to the size of the browser window when a user first goes on the site. From this they navigate down through the rest of the site but you don't see it regardless of the size of the browser window without scrolling ( http://whiteboard.is is a good example of this ).

I'm using the code below and while it stretches horizontally it won't stretch vertically past the min-height. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<section id="first-section">
</section>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html  {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }

#first-section {
    background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
    }
```

Comment: I recommend creating a jsfiddle example before posting such questions: An example http://jsfiddle.net/6VVUG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can write `height:100%` also.

```
#first-section {
    background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat :) Worked this time, didn't work before. Maybe I deleted something that was affecting it haha. Thanks :)